# virsh attach-device for serial device

Tags: virtual-machines, kvm-virtualization, libvirt, virsh

I would like to add a serial device (console) to a guest via the `virsh attach-device` command.
I have a console.xml file containing:

```
<serial type="pty">
  <target port="0"/>
</serial>
```

And I run the following command:

```
sudo virsh attach-device VMNAME console.xml
```

But get the following error:

```
error: Failed to attach device from console.xml
error: XML error: unknown device type
```

Here's my version information:

```
Compiled against library: libvir 0.9.8
Using library: libvir 0.9.8
Using API: QEMU 0.9.8
Running hypervisor: QEMU 1.0.0
```

What am I doing wrong? How can I add this from a script? Any help would be appreciated!!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1):

According to the libvirt [documentation](http://libvirt.org/formatdomain.html#elementsConsole), you also need a *source* element. Something like this:

```
<serial type='pty'>
  <source path='/dev/pts/3'/>
  <target port='0'/>
</serial>
```

Comment: Thanks I'll give this a try when I have a minute and let you kno how it went

Comment: Very late but this gives me the same error:

Comment: Did you use the correct pts number?

Comment: Yes, the thing is. this snipet works if it is inserted manually via virsh edit but it fails via virsh attach-device. I don't have the link but I read somewhere that only a limited number of devices (ie: disks and I forget which others) were supported through attach-device. So I've put this on hold for the time being.

Comment: Is you VM running? 'attach-device' only works on active domains.

Comment: Yes. I still get error: XML error: unknown device type